# Handle 'missing rest service' message in Lucee (or Railo)

Tags: error-handling, coldfusion, cfml, railo, lucee

One of the SANS Web Application Security recommendations is to handle all errors and replace them with a generic, non-descriptive messages.

In Lucee (or Railo for that matter) when I access a REST service address that doesn't exist, I get the `no rest service for [/xxxx] found in mapping [/yyyy]` which doesn't pass through `onError`.

I see that REST is a separate servlet, however, everything else runs through `onRequestStart`, `onRequest`, `onRequestEnd`... etc.

Any suggestions on how to capture or suppress this error?